# How to install apache2 while not removing apache on debian etch?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, aptitude

I'm looking to do an upgrade from apache1.3 to apache2.2.
My plan was to install apache2 with aptitude, but that tells me apache and related packages will be removed, which obviously I don't want as it's up and running.

I'd like to run apache2 on port 81 until I configured everything correctly before putting it on port 80 and shutting down the old apache.

Any ideas? I'm not really a linux expect...

Comment: Seems like an ugly process - do you have any other options for migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't address your specific question but it does address the larger underlying problem.

Debian Etch has been at [End-of-Life](http://www.debian.org/releases/etch/) status since February 2010. That means **no** security updates. If this is a publically facing web server, you will be quite lucky if it hasn't already been successfully hacked. You should upgrade to the current version of Debian Stable (version 6.0). If you do not have the skills to do this yourself nor the time to acquire them, you should hire someone who can. Nothing personal, this is just how it is.

My recommendation is to perform your "upgrade" from Apache to Apache2 by building a new server using Debian 6.0, installing Apache2 and then migrating your website from your old server to the new one. What you suggest will be painful and ultimately unproductive.

Comment: Right, thanks for the help. I'll discuss that with my hosting company to get a decent setup alltogether instead of upgrading just one part.

Comment: I know it's not what you really wanted to hear, but you'll be happy you did it in the end. If you're paying for shared hosting and the platform they are providing is an EOL, you should A) ask for a refund and B) find a new hosting provider.